# Reverse for 'chained_filter' not found. 'chained_filter' is not a valid view function or pattern name Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-smart-selects

I working on a project where I need to add two dependant dropdowns for that I tried to use Django-smart-selects but I having an issue. Here's what I did

**Here is my models**

```
class District(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
created_at = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'District'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class PoliceStation(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
district = models.ForeignKey(
    District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100)
created_at = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'PoliceStation'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class NewsAndUpdates(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
description = HTMLField()
category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100)
district = models.ForeignKey(
    District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

policeStation = ChainedForeignKey(
    PoliceStation,
    chained_field="district",
    chained_model_field="district",
    show_all=False,
    auto_choose=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'NewsAndUpdates'
```

**This is my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

**Here is my installed apps**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
....
'smart_selects',
]
```

In `setting.py` I used this as it was suggested when I was searching about the issue

```
USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True
```

**This is my admin.py**

```
class NewsAndUpdatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('title', 'category', 'created_at',
                'is_published', 'is_draft')

admin.site.register(NewsAndUpdates, NewsAndUpdatesAdmin)
```

But I am getting issue which is
`Reverse for 'chained_filter' not found. 'chained_filter' is not a valid view function or pattern name`

[image: Screenshot]

**Using Django version 3.1**

Comment: Have you run migrate command

Comment: Yes, I ran the migrate command.

Comment: @SatyenChauhan did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @fmakawa not yet

Answer (score 0):

The NoReverseMatch error is saying that Django cannot find a matching url pattern for the url you've provided in any of your installed app's urls. The NoReverseMatch exception is raised by django. ... urlresolvers when a matching URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters supplied.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I followed the Django-smart-selects’s document. What should I add in the url more?

Comment: i think you have a view function or a app that not registered in your url check it in your code

Comment: sometime we pass some argument but we forgot to add that in our url so check that also

Comment: It’s library which I installed I haven’t written any function for this in my view

Comment: its not about your library its about chained_filter where you used chained_filter check there if any url or arguments are missing

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error when I hadn't registered smart_selects.urls in urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Add to /app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls'))
]
```